# Only in samsung mobile image get rotate when uploading from gallery

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'm trying to upload an image from my app everything works fine on the all other device while trying upload from the camera or gallery but when I'm trying to upload the image from gallery->camera folder using device samsung galaxy J6 it gets rotated in image view.when trying to upload from other folder it's working fine only camera folder inside the gallery getting this problem. I searched on google got some answer to use exifinterface but this also didn't help me. This is not showing the selected image in my image view it's executing the catch block.
please help me stuck from last two days.

here is my code:-

```
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                Bitmap converetdImage = getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 200);
                PreferenceManager.saveStringForKey(myContext, AppConstant.PREFERENCE_TAG.IMAGE, AppConstant.getBase64Image(converetdImage));
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
                String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);*/

                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(contentURI.toString());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                }
                else if (orientation == 3) {
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                }
                else if (orientation == 8) {
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                }
               Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

               // imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imgProfile.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                is_image_change = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good question, but you should try to make it more reproducible.  It might be hard for other users to reproduce this problem.

Comment: thanks, @TimBiegeleisen ... is it understandable now

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: FileNotFoundExeption @Henry